# yarn installation error in command prompt

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I have installed yarn through the installer.

When I try to test it through command prompt it shows me the following error.

```
C:\Users\yasal>yarn --version

'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

But it has been installed successfully.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after the installation, or did the installer install yarn globally?

Comment: How did you install it? And did you remember to start a new cmd?

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the terminal, my problem has been resolved. Thanks @Sterling Archer